Using arrays in MACROS [C language]
#define VAR_X     {1,2,3,4}
I am trying to declare arrays in macros like the one above.  I am a little confused about whether it is a correct approach because no compilation error occurs. Let me know the correct approach to declare and use it.

It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Please post a [mre].

That is a valid initializer for an array with no specified size or with a size of at least 4.  Of itself, it does not declare an array.  The initializer could also be used for a structure with at least 4 members of appropriate types.  It is not clear that it's a good macro, but it is valid and has some uses.

You could use a compound literal, e.g., #define ARR (int []){ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, but it isn't clear to me why you would want to do this. You need to describe what it is that you are trying to do if you want to get a good answer.

Why do you need a macro? What's wrong with int somearray[] = {1,2,3,4};. What are you actually trying to achieve? Please [edit] your question.

I believe you are asking if you can use the following:
#define VAR_X {1,2,3,4}

int x[] = VAR_X;

If so, yes. The preprocessor replaces the VAR_X token with a sequence of tokens consisting of {, 1, ,, 2, ,, 3, ,, 4 and }, and this produces valid C code.
Even the following is valid (although illegible):
#define X ] = {
#define Y 1,
#define Z 3,4};

int x[ X Y 2, Z


Upvoted. I love your illegible example! Reminds me of C++ .

@GabrielStaples The IOCCC has tons of examples how to abuse the preprocessor, but you know that for sure.

Preprocessor macros are not C syntax checked as they are not C language.  The preprocessor simply replaces any instance of the macro with its definition before passing the pre-processed source to the compiler.
If after replacement, the result is syntactically malformed, then you will get a error.  The problem is the error will refer to the code after preprocessing, but not normally the expanded to show that.  Consequently complex macros can be hard to debug and are often best avoided.
